# Host a c# backend solution (which contains entity framework) for free

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, rest, server

I programmed a c# solution which includes **Entity Framework** and implemented a **rest service**. Now I want to **host it free** on a server but I dont really know how to do it.

My rest service will be consumed by two mobile applications (Android and iOS).

So could someone explain for me the next steps or can you find a tutorial for me?

Thank you!

Comment: You can look into using Microsoft Azure for the hosting. You can host a free website if you don't use a custom domain and have a small load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Azure for free hosting.

Here you can see the details : [**Create your free Azure account**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/)

This tutorial shows how to deploy an ASP.NET Web Api to an Azure App Service by using the Publish Web wizard in Visual Studio :

Here you'll learn :

- How to use the ASP.NET Web API to enable Restful API calls.
- How to use a SQL database to store data in Azure.
- How to publish application updates to Azure.

[**Create a REST service using ASP.NET Web API and SQL Database in Azure App Service**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database/)

Another good article :

[**ASP.Net Web API: Create, Deploy to Azure and Manage Using Azure API Management**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/g_arora/asp-net-web-api-create-deploy-to-azure-and-manage-using-az/)